# How to show each td data in a card in html automatically after 15 second using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamic, html-table

I am showing data in a table dynamically in a table, I grt json data and show in html table dynamically. There is a card in html with that table, so I want to show each tr data in that card after 15 second means on load the first tr data shows in card and after 15 seconds the second tr data show in that same card and first tr data remove. I want to show each tr data in that card every 15 seconds

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head></head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style type="text/css" media="all">
        body {
                text-align: center;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .card {
                box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                width: 200px;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 10px;
        }

        .tr {
                background: blue;
                color: white;
                transition: background .3s;
        }

        .table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        .table td {
                padding: 10px 15px;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="card">
                <span id="value">25 </span><span id="unit">ppm</span>
                <p id="parameter">Sodium Oxide</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table" border="1">

<thead>
                                <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Parameter</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Alias</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Cordinates</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Location</th>
                                </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="scroll">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                        $.getJSON('./data.json', function(data) {
                                console.log(data)
                                
var tdata = '';
                                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                        console.log(value.deviceId)

                                        tdata += '<tr>' + '<td>' + value.deviceId + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.aliasname + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.cordinates + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.location + '</td>' + '</tr>'

                                })

                        })

                })
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call each DOM modification after a `setTimeout`. Here, I use `async`/`await` syntax:

```js
const tbody = $('#scroll');
const sleep = (millis) => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));

$.getJSON('./data.json', async function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    // Forever loop over the received values
    while(1) {
        // For each value in data, replace table data
        // with new tr containing data's value
        for(const value of data) {
            console.log(value.deviceId);
            tbody.html(`<tr><td>${value.deviceId}</td><td>${value.aliasname}</td><td>${value.cordinates}</td><td>${value.location}</td></tr>`);
            await sleep(15_000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the thing is in this function it shows the td after every 15 sec I don't want the tr to append after every 15 sec I want to show the table data of each row in that HTML card above after every 15 sec

Comment: Do you mean to update the full table data (with a new `getJSON` call) every 15 seconds? Forever?

Comment: Or you mean to replace the `<tr>` with the next one, instead of appending the new one?

Comment: I want to append the table normally as it happen but I want to show the data in that row in a different html card above. The table append normally as it is but I want to show the data of each row in that html card after every 15 sec.. When the page load the first tr data show in that card after 15 sec the second tr data show in that card like wise all tr

Comment: So, you want the table to be filled completely (as you do in your question), but all rows hidden, and then, show a new row every 15 seconds and remove the previous one?

Comment: you misunderstood my point or may be I am not able to explain you ....... I don't want the row hidden I want the row to be filled normally as it is.. The main thing is to show the data of the row in a different card as you can see in question there is card first so I want to show the row data in that card one by one each row . First I want to show the data of  first row in that card after 15 sec the second row data after 15 sec the third row data and similarly all the row data one by one with time of 15 seconds

Comment: `The main thing is to show the data of the row in a different card` I can only see **one** card, and this is the first time you mention a second card. Sorry, you explain yourself very badly.

Comment: Not in the second card I want to show in that one card only the code you give is append each row after 15 seconds... Forget everything... I try to explain....

Comment: I have a json file from which I get data and append it in a table simply without any animation... For eg there are 3 rows in a table, so I want to show the first row data in a card as shown above after 15 seconds I want to show the second row data in that card and after 15 seconds the third row data. I want to show each row data one by one in that card.

Comment: Simple eg. There are three rows in a table with people names. First row td is "Azhar" , Second row td is "emi" and third row td is "stack". There is a card in above in which the first row data appear that is "Azhar" after 15 seconds the "Azhar" is remove and show " emi" which is second row data and 15 sec "emi" removed and show "stack" and then again start from "Azhar"... May this will explain my Question.. Thank you for your time

Comment: Edited the answer. Is that what you look for?

Comment: Not exactly the same but it helps me a lot and thank you so much, really thanks a lot fo tr your precious time brother.. It helps me a lot really, I want the whole table data and show that in the card one by one but from here I can manage because of your help only, once again thank you so much